# Ghostscript - Specify dpi for an image

Tags: ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

I am currently using ImageMagick to extract page images of a pdf document. I need the page images in different dpi's.

The convert command used is

```
exec('convert -density 500 "' . $filefullpath . '" -resample ' . $dpi . '%d.jpg');
```

Since convert method is very much time consuming, I have decided to replace this with gs command.

The gs command currently written is

```
exec('gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage='.$params['startPage'].' -dLastPage='.$params['endPage'].' -sOutputFile=%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r ' . $params['dpi'] . ' -q "' . $params['filefullpath'] . '" -c quit', $result);
```

-r param is used to specify the dpi.

My required dpi are 50, 100, 125, 150, 200 & 300

Convert command returns the output correctly with good quality. But gs command does not return in the required dpi and also the quality is not good.

Can someone help me to revise my gs command to achieve expected results?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete space symbol after `-r '` => `-r'`:

```
exec('gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage='.$params['startPage'].' -dLastPage='.$params['endPage'].' -sOutputFile=%d.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r' . $params['dpi'] . ' -q "' . $params['filefullpath'] . '" -c quit', $result);
```

Comment: Yes. you are right. This is copy-paste issue. The actual statement does not have space. it is "-r'"

Comment: You are using JPEG, so the quality will not be as good as a lossless format. You aren't using any kind of anti-aliasing (neither an anti-aliasing device, nor -dGraphicsAlphaBits and -dGraphicsTextBits). Even with the addition of those, you can't reasonably expect a PostScript rip to do the same kind of job as a full-blown image manipulation tool. I would 'guess' that ImageMagick is rendering to high resolution and using sophisticated filters to reduce the resolution while retaining quality. This, of course, is what takes the time. So you can have it fast, or good, your choice.